# Display name instead of DB value in SonataAdmin List View

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I'm having a problem when I try to list the record from DB since I get the value stored in row which is a integer but I want the string instead. How I'm handling the form? In this way:

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form) {
    $form
            ->add('no_order', null, array('label' => 'No. Order'))
            ->add('company', 'entity', array('class' => 'PL\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company', 'label' => 'Cliente'))
            ->add('business_case', null, array('label' => 'BC'))
            ->add('charge_status', 'choice', array('choices' => array(
                    "empty_value" => "Seleccione una opción",
                    "0" => "Ninguno",
                    "1" => "Proceso de Fabricacion",
                    "2" => "Pickup en destino",
                    "3" => "A la espera de recojo por cliente",
                    "4" => "Carga en transito",
                    "5" => "Carga arribada",
                    "6" => "En proceso de aduana",
                    "7" => "Entregado a cliente",
                    "8" => "En bodega"
                ), "required" => true, 'label' => 'Estado de la carga'))
            ->add('eta', null, array('label' => 'ETA', 'widget' => 'single_text', 'required' => false, 'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker')))
            ->add('etd', null, array('label' => 'ETD', 'widget' => 'single_text', 'required' => false, 'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker')))
            ->add('transport_media', 'choice', array('choices' => array("empty_value" => "Seleccione una opción", "0" => "EXW", "1" => "Maritimo", "2" => "Aereo"), "required" => true, 'label' => 'Via de Transporte'))
            ->add('incoterm', 'choice', array('choices' => array(
                    "empty_value" => "Seleccione una opción",
                    "0" => "Ninguno",
                    "1" => "EWX",
                    "2" => "FOB",
                    "3" => "CIF",
                    "4" => "DDP"
                ), "required" => true, 'label' => 'Incoterm'))
            ->add('comments', null, array('label' => 'Comentarios'))
            ->with('Documentos')
            ->add('medias', 'sonata_type_collection', array(
                'required' => false), array(
                'edit' => 'inline',
                'inline' => 'table',
                'sortable' => 'position'))
            ->end();
}
```

I define `charge_status` (is the equivalent to BC in view) as choice, how I can show the string and not the value in the list view? See the attached image for visual of the problem

[image]

Comment: `empty_value` shouldn't live in the array of choices but be a separate option in the main options-array.

Comment: This behavior is strange ... Did you try to flip keys and values in those choices arrays ? Where exactly are you fetching those from database?! i can't find that in your code.

Comment: @nifr I don't follow you, could you please post a example?

Comment: You have an array of the form `'1' => 'text string'`. Now `1` is the key and `text string` is the value. you want your choice field to show `text string` instead of `1` , right ? just switch the keys and values of the array and make it look like `'text string' => '1'`. You can use `array_flip(array('1' => 'text string' ...` , too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach:

define a static  array in your entity for example:

```
<?php
class Entity 
{
    public static $chargeStatusList = array(
                "0" => "Ninguno",
                "1" => "Proceso de Fabricacion",
                "2" => "Pickup en destino",
                "3" => "A la espera de recojo por cliente",
                "4" => "Carga en transito",
                "5" => "Carga arribada",
                "6" => "En proceso de aduana",
                "7" => "Entregado a cliente",
                "8" => "En bodega"
            );

    public function getChargeStatusValue()
    {
        return self::$chargeStatus[$this->charge_status];
    }

}
```

In your Admin class

```
class YourAdmin extends Admin
{

    ....
    use Path/To/Your/Entity;
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
   {
        $listMapper
            ->add('chargeStatusValue', 'string', array('label' => 'Charge status'))

    ;
   }

   protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $form) 
   {
       ....
       ->add('charge_status', 'choice', array('choices' => Entity::$chargeStatusList));
       ....
   }
}
```